# How to sort a HashSet?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, set, hashset

For lists, we use the `Collections.sort(List)` method. What if we want to sort a `HashSet`?

Comment: A `HashSet` is an unordered collection.

Comment: You can't, since a `Set` does not have random access methods (ie, `.get()` an element at a given index), which is basically required for sort algorithms ;)

Comment: You could convert it to a list first then sort if you need to sort

Comment: You can't since a `HashSet` doesn't have a defined order. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: use a TreeSet and if you can't control the source see the conversion an usage here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52987487/5153955

Comment: The following answer can be very helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59964344/7397820

Answer (score 155):

A HashSet does not guarantee any order of its elements. If you need this guarantee, consider using a TreeSet to hold your elements.

However if you just need your elements sorted for this one occurrence, then just temporarily create a List and sort that:

```
Set<?> yourHashSet = new HashSet<>();

...

List<?> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(yourHashSet);
Collections.sort(sortedList);
```

Comment: Also, if you're using a collection of Strings, then `List<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<String>(yourHashSet);`

Comment: I got this error: 
The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ?>)

Answer (score 89):

Add all your objects to the [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), you will get a sorted Set. Below is a raw example.

```
HashSet myHashSet = new HashSet();
myHashSet.add(1);
myHashSet.add(23);
myHashSet.add(45);
myHashSet.add(12);

TreeSet myTreeSet = new TreeSet();
myTreeSet.addAll(myHashSet);
System.out.println(myTreeSet); // Prints [1, 12, 23, 45]
```

### Update

You can also use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)'s constructor that takes a `HashSet` as a parameter.

```
HashSet myHashSet = new HashSet();
myHashSet.add(1);
myHashSet.add(23);
myHashSet.add(45);
myHashSet.add(12);

TreeSet myTreeSet = new TreeSet(myHashSet);
System.out.println(myTreeSet); // Prints [1, 12, 23, 45]
```

*Thanks @mounika for the update.*

Comment: By using `TreeSet myTreeSet = new TreeSet(myHashSet);` you can avoid adding all the elements to Treeset again.

Comment: This will remove duplicates as OP asking to sort HashSet and it may contain duplicate values.

Comment: Hashset may contain duplicate values!! Really!??

Answer (score 26):

Java 8 way to sort it would be:

```
fooHashSet.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getSize)) //comparator - how you want to sort it
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collector - what you want to collect it to
```

*`Foo::getSize` it's an example how to sort the HashSet of YourItem's naturally by size.

*`Collectors.toList()` is going to collect the result of sorting into a List the you will need to capture it with `List<Foo> sortedListOfFoo =`

Comment: Can you please, Add the logic to sort it in a specific order ?

Comment: @Jess i dont know whats the specific order for you Jess, you can sort it as you desire using the comparator.

Comment: I meant, how to define the Ascending or Descending

Comment: Are there any advantages of doing your solution over `List<?> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(yourHashSet);
Collections.sort(sortedList);`?

Answer (score 21):

You can use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead.

Comment: Just putting the elements wont give the flexibility of sorting on any order with any element inside it. The above solution does.

Answer (score 16):

Use `java.util.TreeSet` as the actual object. When you iterate over this collection, the values come back in a well-defined order.

If you use `java.util.HashSet` then the order depends on an internal hash function which is almost certainly not lexicographic (based on content).

Comment: Why are you assuming they store `String` values?

Comment: I'm not though perhaps my use of lexographic is imprecise ;-)

Comment: It's very wrong. It doesn't store keys in lexographic (sp?) order. It either uses their natural ordering (which depends on `Comparable` interface which the keys implement) or uses the provided `Comparator`.

Comment: I've edited. Better do you think , or should I delete the answer?

Comment: I would just quote the javadoc.

Comment: In case you move a `HashSet` to `TreeSet`, your class must implement `Comparable` interface or provide a custom `Comparator`. Otherwise, since you cannot sort a `HashSet`, just convert it into a `List` and sort it.

Comment: I guess,I can use  TreeSet with the constructor- TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator).

Answer (score 13):

Just in-case you don't wanna use a `TreeSet` you could try this using java stream for concise code.

```java
set = set.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Comment: Why use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Java 8 collectors and TreeSet

`list.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))`

Comment: `new TreeSet<>(hashSet)` is more concise and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Elements in HashSet can't be sorted. Whenever you put elements into HashSet, it can mess up the ordering of the whole set. It is deliberately designed like that for performance. When you don't care about the order, HashSet will be the most efficient set for frequent insertions and queries.

TreeSet is the alternative that you can use. When you iterate on the tree set, you will get sorted elements automatically.
But it will adjust the tree to try to remain sorted every time you insert an element.

Perhaps, what you are trying to do is to sort just once. In that case, TreeSet is not the most efficient option because it needs to determine the placing of newly added elements all the time. Use TreeSet only when you want to sort often.

If you only need to sort once, use ArrayList. Create a new list and add all the elements then sort it once. If you want to retain only unique elements (remove all duplicates), then put the list into a LinkedHashSet, it will retain the order you have already sorted.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(6);
list.add(4);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
Collections.sort(list);
Set<Integer> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(list); // 4 5 6
```

Now, you've gotten a sorted set if you want it in a list form then convert it into list.

Comment: Your statement "TreeSet will sort all the elements automatically every time you insert an element" is untrue. If you change the value used for comparing of an object in the list, and then add a new object it will be placed as if the object you changed has its original value. Thus only the new item gets placed in the list at the correct point assuming none of the elements changed their value used to sort the list.

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo Thanks. I've edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer given by @LazerBanana i will put my own example of a Set sorted by the Id of the Object:

```java
Set<Clazz> yourSet = [...];

yourSet.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Clazz>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Clazz o1, Clazz o2) {
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList()); // Returns the sorted List (using toSet() wont work)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use TreeSet as mentioned in other answers.

Here's a little more elaboration on how to use it:

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();
ts.add("b1");
ts.add("b3");
ts.add("b2");
ts.add("a1");
ts.add("a2");
System.out.println(ts);
for (String s: ts)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
```

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion , LazerBanana's answer should be the top rated answer & accepted because all the other answers pointing to `java.util.TreeSet` ( or first convert to list then call `Collections.sort(...)` on the converted list ) didn't bothered to ask OP as what kind of objects your `HashSet` has i.e. if those elements have a predefined **natural ordering** or not & that is not optional question but a  mandatory question.

You just can't go in & start putting your `HashSet` elements into a `TreeSet` if element type doesn't already implement `Comparable` interface or if you are not explicitly passing `Comparator` to `TreeSet` constructor.

From `TreeSet` JavaDoc ,

> Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the natural
>   ordering of its elements. All elements inserted into the set must
>   implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all such elements
>   must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a
>   ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set. If the user
>   attempts to add an element to the set that violates this constraint
>   (for example, the user attempts to add a string element to a set whose
>   elements are integers), the add call will throw a ClassCastException.

That is why only all Java8 stream based answers - where you define your comparator on the spot -  only make sense because implementing comparable in POJO becomes optional. Programmer defines comparator as and when needed. Trying to collect into `TreeSet` without asking this fundamental question is also incorrect ( Ninja's answer). Assuming object types to be `String` or `Integer` is also incorrect.

Having said that, other concerns like ,

1. Sorting Performance
2. Memory Foot Print ( retaining original set and creating new sorted sets each time sorting is done or wish to sort the set in - place etc etc )

should be the other relevant points too. Just pointing to API shouldn't be only intention.

Since Original set already contains only **unique** elements & that constraint is  also maintained by sorted set so original set needs to be cleared from memory since data is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Add all set element in list -> al.addAll(s);
2. Sort all the elements in list using -> Collections.sort(al);


 public class SortSetProblem {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add("ved");
    s.add("prakash");
    s.add("sharma");
    s.add("apple");
    s.add("ved");
    s.add("banana");
    System.out.println("Before Sorting");
    for (String s1 : s) {
        System.out.print("  " + s1);
    }

    System.out.println("After Sorting");
    al.addAll(s);
    Collections.sort(al);
    for (String set : al) {
        System.out.print(" " + set);
    }
  }
 }
```

> input - ved prakash sharma apple ved banana
>
> Output - apple banana prakash sharma ved

Answer (score 1):

If you want want the end `Collection` to be in the form of `Set` and if you want to define your own `natural order` rather than that of `TreeSet` then -

1. Convert the `HashSet` into `List`
2. Custom sort the `List` using `Comparator`
3. Convert back the `List` into `LinkedHashSet` to maintain order
4. Display the `LinkedHashSet`

   Sample program -

```
package demo31;

import java.util.*;
public class App26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        addElements(set);
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list = convertToList(set);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                int flag = s2.length() - s1.length();
                if(flag != 0) {
                    return flag;
                } else {
                    return -s1.compareTo(s2);
                }
            }
        });
        Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        set2 = convertToSet(list);
        displayElements(set2);
    }
    public static void addElements(Set<String> set) {
        set.add("Hippopotamus");
        set.add("Rhinocerous");
        set.add("Zebra");
        set.add("Tiger");
        set.add("Giraffe");
        set.add("Cheetah");
        set.add("Wolf");
        set.add("Fox");
        set.add("Dog");
        set.add("Cat");
    }
    public static List<String> convertToList(Set<String> set) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for(String element: set) {
            list.add(element);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static Set<String> convertToSet(List<String> list) {
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for(String element: list) {
            set.add(element);
        }
        return set;
    }
    public static void displayElements(Set<String> set) {
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Output -

```
[Hippopotamus, Rhinocerous, Giraffe, Cheetah, Zebra, Tiger, Wolf, Fox, Dog, Cat]
```

Here the collection has been sorted as -

First - Descending order of `String` length
Second - Descending order of `String` alphabetical hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in the following ways:

Method 1:

1. Create a list and store all the hashset values into it
2. sort the list using Collections.sort()
3. Store the list back into LinkedHashSet as it preserves the insertion order

Method 2:

- Create a treeSet and store all the values into it.

Method 2 is more preferable because the other method consumes lot of time to transfer data back and forth between hashset and list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava library for the same

```
Set<String> sortedSet = FluentIterable.from(myHashSet).toSortedSet(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        // descending order of relevance
        //required code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not decide that the elements of a HashSet would be sorted automatically. But we can sort them by converting into TreeSet or any List like ArrayList or LinkedList etc.

```
// Create a TreeSet object of class E
TreeSet<E> ts = new TreeSet<E> ();

// Convert your HashSet into TreeSet
ts.addAll(yourHashSet);

System.out.println(ts.toString() + "\t Sorted Automatically");
```

Answer (score 0):

SortedSet has been added Since java 7
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a TreeSet like this:

```
Set mySet = new HashSet();
mySet.add(4);
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add(3);
mySet.add(1);
System.out.println("mySet items "+ mySet);   

TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet(mySet);   
System.out.println("treeSet items "+ treeSet);
```

output :
mySet items [1, 3, 4, 5]
treeSet items [1, 3, 4, 5]

```
Set mySet = new HashSet();
mySet.add("five");
mySet.add("elf");
mySet.add("four");
mySet.add("six");
mySet.add("two");
System.out.println("mySet items "+ mySet);

TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet(mySet);
System.out.println("treeSet items "+ treeSet);
```

output:
mySet items [six, four, five, two, elf]
treeSet items [elf, five, four, six, two]

requirement for this method is that the objects of the set/list should be comparable (implement the Comparable interface)

Answer (score 0):

The below is my sample code and its already answered by pointing the code in comments , am still sharing because it contains the complete code

```
package Collections;

import java.util.*;

public class TestSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> objset = new HashSet<>();

        objset.add("test");
        objset.add("abc");
        objset.add("abc");
        objset.add("mas");
        objset.add("vas");

        Iterator itset = objset.iterator();
        while(itset.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itset.next());
        }

        TreeSet<String> treeobj = new TreeSet(objset);
        System.out.println(treeobj);


    }
}
```

TreeSet treeobj = new TreeSet(objset); here we are invoking the treeset constructor which will call the addAll method to add the objects .

See this below code from the TreeSet class how its mentioned ,

```
public TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        this();
        addAll(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `HashSet` to `List` then sort it using `Collection.sort()`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hset);
Collections.sort(List)
```

Answer (score -4):

This simple command did the trick for me:

```
myHashSet.toList.sorted
```

I used this within a print statement, so if you need to actually persist the ordering, you may need to use TreeSets or other structures proposed on this thread.

Comment: I don't see where HashSet or Set has a method `toList`.

Comment: That looks like Scala to me, which unfortunately doesn't solve the problem in Java.

Comment: toList method , How is possible ?