# Why do we need List to sort using Collection.sort() method?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, collections, compareto

I am planning to sort keys from a hashmap. I am using a customized sort method.

Following code gives me **compile-time error** on *compareTo()* method where I am using **Set** as Collection

```
Set<String> set = map.keySet();
Collections.sort(set, (a, b) -> map.get(a) == map.get(b) ?  a.compareTo(b) : map.get(b) - map.get(a));
```

If I convert **Set to List** and then sort then everything **works fine**.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(words, (a, b) -> map.get(a) == map.get(b) ?  a.compareTo(b) : map.get(b) - map.get(a));
```

What is the reason that I need to convert to List to sort the collection? Why can't I sort using Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set` has no API to change the order. You will notice yourself if you try, e.g. to swap the first and second elements of a `Set`.

Further, sets have their own contracts regarding the order which would be violated if you could change it from the outside

- `HashSet` and the key set of a `HashMap` do not maintain an order at all. This is the general assumption for sets if no other contract is specified
- `LinkedHashSet` and the key set of a `LinkedHashMap` will reflect the insertion order
- `TreeSet` and the key set of a `TreeMap` use the natural order of the keys or the order of an explicitly specified comparator. All implementations of `SortedSet` are bound to a `Comparator` or the natural order of the keys.

In order to sort something you need a collection which maintains an order and has an API supporting to alter the order.

A `List` is a natural candidate. You can also sort arrays. Since `LinkedHashMap` reflects the insertion order, you can create a `LinkedHashMap` with a specific order by adding the elements in the desired order:

```
map = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                              (a,b)->b, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Besides, your comparator looks broken. The term `map.get(b) - map.get(a)` indicates that the values are numerical, in the examples above I assumed `Integer`, but `map.get(a) == map.get(b)` compares the *references* of the boxed objects.

And in case of `Integer`, the difference `map.get(b) - map.get(a)` can overflow. You should use `Integer.compare(map.get(b), map.get(a)` instead.

Or use the factory methods for comparators whenever applicable

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
words.sort(Comparator.<String>comparingInt(map::get).reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition in Java, **`Set` is NOT an ordered collection.**

We can’t sort a Java `Set` collection by calling `Collections.sort()` method on a Set.

There is no direct support for sorting the sets in Java. To sort a set, follow these steps:

- Convert set to list.
- Sort list using `Collections.sort()` API.
- Convert list back to set.

**OR**

We can use a sorted implementation of set.

According to the following diagram **`HashSet`**, **`LinkedHashSet`**, and **`TreeSet`** are implementations of Set.

- `HashSet`: Unordered
- `LinkedHashSet`: Insertion order
- `TreeSet`: Ordered (natural order i.e. alphabetic, alphanumeric or chronological)

*Note: `HashSet` is the default implementation used in most cases.*

[image]

Diagram Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/an-introduction-to-the-java-collections-framework